# Match check cells from two sheets to match then copy column to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am puzzled how to achieve the following items in Excel VBA. I saw a lot of tutorials but everyone is talking about move the entire row of a pre-defined text/number in the VBA, which isn't what I hoped to do.

My objective is to:

1. first, I need to use ID cell on Sheet1 as a master, I need to compare each of those ID cells with entire column of ID cells on Sheet2 to find a match repeatedly
2. If there is a match, copy a selective number of columns on the same row of ID cell (that matched with Sheet1's ID cell) on the Sheet2 to Sheet1 next to Sheet1's ID cell, then the process repeated for all ID cells

Vlookup can only do it for the first cells, but because there are many cells with cell value but the content on the selective column I am trying to copy to the Sheet1 from Sheet2 is different.

Please help for come up ideas how to achieve it on VBA. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you share the code you've got? There is not enough information. Which column in Sheet1 should be looked up in which column of Sheet2? In the case of a match, which columns of Sheet2 should be returned in which columns of Sheet1? What is the first row of Sheet1 and of Sheet2? Take a look at an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717130) that could easily be modified to suit your case.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sheet1 column A (header ID) contains : id01, id02, id03 ---> cell A2:A4. There is nothing to the rest of the column in sheet1. In sheet2 column A contains the ID : id01, id03 ---> cell A2:A3, where B2 to F2 contains "x" and B3 to F3 contains "y". Expected result after running the sub : in Sheet1, cell B2:F2 value = "x" ... B3:F3 value = nothing ... B4:F4 value = "y". Something like that ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.